# Why my program can't see that there is a registry key?

Tags: c#, windows, ms-word, registry, registrykey

I am trying to check which versions of Word are installed on user's computer.

This is the code I am using:

```
    public static bool CheckIfWordVersionIsInstalled(int wordVersion)
    {
        var path32 = "Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\" + WordVersionKeyToValue(wordVersion) + "\\Word\\InstallRoot";
        var path64 = "Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Office\\" + WordVersionKeyToValue(wordVersion) + "\\Word\\InstallRoot";

        var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path32, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);   
        Tools.Log("WordTools.CheckIfWordVersionIsInstalled: " + (key != null) + ": " + path32);

        if (key == null)
        {
            key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path64, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
            Tools.Log("WordTools.CheckIfWordVersionIsInstalled: " + (key != null) + ": " + path64);
        }

        return key != null;
    }
```

In my log I can see keys that have been checked:

```
[16:36:57]WordTools.CheckIfWordVersionIsInstalled: False: Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\InstallRoot
[16:36:57]WordTools.CheckIfWordVersionIsInstalled: False: Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\InstallRoot
[16:36:57]WordTools.CheckIfWordVersionIsInstalled: False: Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\InstallRoot
[16:36:57]WordTools.CheckIfWordVersionIsInstalled: False: Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\InstallRoot
[16:36:57]WordTools.CheckIfWordVersionIsInstalled: False: Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\InstallRoot
[16:36:57]WordTools.CheckIfWordVersionIsInstalled: False: Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\InstallRoot
[16:36:57]WordTools.CheckIfWordVersionIsInstalled: False: Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\InstallRoot
[16:36:57]WordTools.CheckIfWordVersionIsInstalled: False: Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\InstallRoot
[16:36:57]WordTools.CheckIfWordVersionIsInstalled: False: Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Word\InstallRoot
[16:36:57]WordTools.CheckIfWordVersionIsInstalled: False: Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Word\InstallRoot
```

You can see that all of them returned False. But when I open my registry, I can clearly see that there is an existing key: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\InstallRoot

How is that possible?
My program is compiled as x86 (I tried also Any CPU but with the same result). Word is also x86.

Comment: Are you running your application As Administrator? Not just using an admin account on the computer, but actually running your application As Administrator.

Comment: No. I tried to check what would happen (same thing), but I need it to work for users, that are not in administrators group.

Comment: works on my machine~

Comment: I would try doing var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\16.0\\Word\\InstallRoot") directly. just in case there is any invisible character returned from WordVersionKeyToValue

Comment: If you see that key there then you have the 64-bit version of Office installed.  And yes, your program will fail as described.  Use RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey() so you can specify the view.  Or favor Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the Prefer 32-bit checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `AnyCPU` should work fine (on 64-bit Windows). For sure `x86` does not work. When you run a 32-bit program then all access to Registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software` are automatically redirected to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node`, thus you have no access to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software` from a 32-bit application.

See also [Registry Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx)

Apart from that you mixed the path. `Wow6432Node` is used for 32bit not vice versa.

**Update:**

My Statement "you have no access to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software` from a 32-bit application" is not fully correct. You can access them, however looks like you have to use the API call, you cannot access them directly by `Registry` Class, see [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You are of course right, but there was one little thing missing - I had to uncheck the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox. Now it works as expected on Any CPU.